# thajeztah/pgadmin4 to locally installed postgresql

Tags: docker

I was able to run "sudo docker run --rm -p 5050:5050 thajeztah/pgadmin4" to start the pgadmin4 web app at 0.0.0.0:5050.  I would like to connect to my locally installed (not dockerized) postgresql.  What ip address should i use when I setup "add new server"?

i am using Linux Mint 18.4.  PostgreSQL 9.6.7 is running on localhost:5432

TIA,

Thomas

Comment: To connect pgadmin4 with a database running in a host you have to modify two files in the host, pg-hba.conf and postgresql.conf

Comment: i also tested with "docker run --net=host --rm -p 5050:5050 thajeztah/pgadmin4".  i guess --net=host means you can use "localhost" as the ip address.  I think this is easier than modifying the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.  This is how i got the docker pgadmin4 to connect to my local postgresql.

1. ifconfig -a : this will show me the ip address for docker0.
2. edit postgresql.conf  : listen_addresses = '*'.  Used to be 127.0.0.1
3. edit pg_hba.conf : i've added host all all 0.0.0.0/0 to IPv4 and IPv6.

Then i restarted the posgresql server.  I've used the ip address from step 1.

Comment: or "docker run --net=host --rm -p 5050:5050 thajeztah/pgadmin4" then you can use "localhost" as the ip address for the server.  Maybe this is easier than to update both .conf files..